# Is there a name for "maybe mzero return"?

Tags: haskell, alternative-functor, monadplus

Is there an established name for `maybe mzero return`?

It has the type:

```
MonadPlus m => Maybe a -> m a
```

and converts `Nothing` to failure and `Just a` to `return a`.

Answer (score 8):

- `optparse-applicative` has [`hoistMaybe`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.17/optparse-applicative-0.12.1.0/src/Options-Applicative-Internal.html#hoistMaybe).
- `monad-extras` has [`liftMaybe`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.17/monad-extras-0.5.11/src/Control-Monad-Extra.html#liftMaybe).
- `errors` has [`justZ`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.17/errors-2.1.2/src/Control-Error-Safe.html#justZ).
- `IfElse` has [`maybeMP`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.17/IfElse-0.85/src/Control-Monad-IfElse.html#maybeMP)

All of the above are the same.

An obvious variant would be

```
maybeAlt :: Alternative f => Maybe a -> f a
maybeAlt = maybe empty pure
```

And this is a special case of the following, similar to `asum`.

```
import Data.Monoid
import Control.Applicative

foldAlt :: (Foldable f, Alternative m) => f a -> m a
foldAlt = getAlt . foldMap (Alt . pure)
```

The reason you won't find this anywhere is that `pure a <|> x === pure a`. So it's good for this and not much else. It could be improved to

```
foldAltMap f = getAlt . foldMap (Alt . f)
```

or

```
foldrAltMap f = foldr (\x r -> f x <|> r) empty
```

but it's probably clearer just to write it out.

Comment: I was wondering if the community has come around to a consensus as to what it should be called. Seems like a candidate for inclusion in `base` somewhere.

Comment: @ErikR, I don't know about that. Sorry.

Comment: @dfeuer Perhaps `foldAlt = asum . fmap pure` makes it more clear exactly how it is similar to `asum`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, that has a rather more restrictive type. Can that be fixed? There's also an operational difference; I imagine the `asum` way is often (usually?) better, but I don't know if it always is. One option is `foldAlt = foldr (\x r -> pure x <|> r) empty`.